# Clarification about the close method in Python file handling

Tags: python

I apologize if this will sound like a basic question but I'm seeking clarification on the close method in python, I am not understanding why after closing the file I can still print the variable that points to the file

if I run the below:

```
poem1 = open('poem1.txt', 'r')

poem_line1 = poem1.readline()
poem_line2 = poem1.readline()
poem_line3 = poem1.readline()

print(poem_line1 + poem_line2 + poem_line3)

poem1.close()

print(poem1.readline())
```

I will get the correct message:

"ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."

but if I replace the last line directly printing the file, there is no error:

```
poem_line1 = poem1.readline()
poem_line2 = poem1.readline()
poem_line3 = poem1.readline()

print(poem_line1 + poem_line2 + poem_line3)

poem1.close()

print (poem_line1 + poem_line2 + poem_line3)
```

Comment: What did you expect the first version of your code to do? Surely calling `readline` again should let you print the fourth line from the file, rather than re-printing the first three lines as your working version does.

Comment: Sorry, you’re right my code is a little misleading, in the second version of the code I could have put only one of the variable but I just wanted to understand why I could still print any of the variable when the file has been closed, but I guess I had my answer which is that the variable was in memory and that’s where I’m printing from and not from the file; that’s why I was confused :-)

Answer (score 2):

The line `poem_line1 = poem1.readline()` reads a line from the file and put it as a string in a variable. So after that the line is copied on the memory. This is the reason why you can still use this variable after closing the file.

So with the line `print (poem_line1 + poem_line2 + poem_line3)` you are not printing from the file, you are printing the string from the variables (from the memory).

Comment: Thanks a lot your answer is very appreciated my friend ,God bless!

Answer (score 1):

The method `close()` closes the opened file. A closed file cannot be read or written any more.

Any operation, which requires that the file be opened will raise a `ValueError` after the file has been closed.Python automatically closes a file when the reference object of a file is reassigned to another file. It is a good practice to use the `close()` method to close a file. Once you close the file you can not print those file because they are not open your compiler will not find anything.

Comment: This does not fully answer the question. Further, the last line is a little misleading.